# Application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality integral version.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have trouble showing the following problem.

Suppose that $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove that for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ we have 
$$|f(x)| \le \sqrt{\int_0^1|f'|^2}$$
Hint: Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $f'$ and $1$ on $[0,1]$ we have 
$$(\int_0^1f')^2 \le \int_0^1(f')^2 * \int_0^11;$$

since $f(0)=0$ this gives 
$$f(1)^2\le\int_0^1(f')^2$$
So I've shown the result holds for $|f(1)|$, however, I don't know how I can show that the inequality holds for all $x \in [0,1]$ using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(0) = 0$, by the FTC $$f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\, dt$$

Hence, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$|f(x)| \le \left(\int_0^x 1\, dt\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\, dt\right)^{1/2}  = x^{1/2} \left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\, dt\right)^{1/2} \le \left(\int_0^1 |f'(t)|^2\, dt\right)^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)|^2 =|\int_0^x f^\prime(t)dt|^2=|\int_0^1\chi_{[0,x]}(t) f^\prime(t)dt|^2$$
Now proceed as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| = |\displaystyle \int_{0}^x 1\cdot f'(t)dt|$, and use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ! and note that $|\displaystyle \int_{0}^x 1^2 dt| = |x| \leq 1$.