# $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt{\int_0 ^1 |f'|^2}$ Solution verification

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Note**

*After finishing my proof, I found a dupe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136646/754927). Apologies if this needs to be closed/removed. I thought I'd submit it anyway just to see if my proof looks ok, and to get feedback on the $f(0)$ vanishing part, which isn't really addressed in the linked question.*

**Question**

Looking for solution verification:

This is from Calculus by Michael Spivak, Chapter 14, problem 22.

> 14-22. Suppose that $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that for all $x$ in [0,1] we have
> $$|f(x)| \leq \sqrt{\int_0 ^1 |f'|^2}.$$
> Show that the hypothesis $f(0) = 0$ is needed. Hint: Problem 13-39.

The hint refers to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ \left(\int_a ^b fg\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_a^b f^2\right)\left(\int_a^b g^2\right)$$

From the Second FTC we have for $x$ in $[0,1]$
$$\int_0^x f' = f(x) - f(0) = f(x)$$
Squaring both sides
$$[f(x)]^2 = \left(\int_0^x f'\right)^2$$
Applying Cauchy-Schwarz to the above expression (using functions $f'$ and $g = 1$), we have
$$[f(x)]^2 =\left(\int_0^x f'\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_0^x f'^2\right) \left(\int_0^x 1^2\right)$$
$$[f(x)]^2 \leq x\int_0^x f'^2$$
Here, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, and the integrand $f'^2$ is nonnegative, so we have
$$x\int_0^x f'^2 \leq 1\int_0^1 f'^2$$

Thus
$$[f(x)]^2 \leq \int_0^1 f'^2$$

Taking the positive square root yields the desired inequality

$$|f(x)| \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}$$

**The $f(0) = 0$ part**

As for showing that the hypothesis $f(0) = 0$ is needed, I'm not sure what to do.

If we couldn't remove $f(0)$ the final inequality would instead look like
$$|f(x) - f(0)| \leq \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}$$
Is this sufficient? Am I missing something important?

Comment: $f(0)$ is needed because of the counterexample $f(x)\equiv 1$

Comment: and proof looks ok

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality integral version.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136634/application-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-integral-version)

Comment: I see that if $f$ is some nonzero constant, the inequality doesn't hold, but if that's all we're worried about, it seems oddly roundabout that we can deal with it by fixing $f(0) = 0$...I'll read your link. Thank you!

Comment: @Calvin Khor I included the same link in my question. :)

Comment: A nonzero constant $f$ is just one counter-example of how the theorem fails when $f(0) \ne 0$. Yes, the result could be modified to $|f(x) - f(0)| \le \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f'|^2}$, which is an easily corrolary of the current statement. And that is the point: They chose to set $f(0) = 0$ because that is all they needed for whatever purpose they are building towards. It was not a case of "this is the only way to fix it", but of "this is the most convenient way to get what we need at this point".

Comment: Interesting. The result reminds me of previous problems about calculating the length over a parameterized curve. This looks kinda similar to those problems, but with the horizontal contribution to the curve removed.